# Can't add any elements to relative divs which are in one line

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to get two relative positioning divs in one line, and code works fine, but it is turning into one big mess when I'm trying to add some elements into one of them. Why is that happening? How to fix it?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #222;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.kiddo {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.first {
  background: pink;
}

.second {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="kiddo first">
    <!-- divs are in one line only when they doesn't contain any elements -->
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="kiddo second"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your paragraph is adding to the height of that element. Put borders around both DIV and see that...

Answer (score 0):

apply `float:left` to `.kiddo` an then it works fine